# Unable to initiate input command without while True: ?. Importance and alternates for while True:?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn python3. Getting ahead but input commands confuse me, since they do not launch on their own? I have no formal education in the subject, besides google and youtube. I know I am missing something basic.

I've looked on www. Would appreciate a detailed explanation?

```
def take_input():
    print (" ")
    city = input("which city do you wish to travel to? \n Options are: delhi, kolkata, bombay, bengaluru : ")
    city.lower()
    print (" ")
    days = int(input("How many days are you travelling for? eg 1 - 100 : ")) 
    nights = days - 1
    print (" ")
    spending_money = int(input("How much spending money do you plan on carrying?, eg 100 - 10000 : "))
    return city, days, spending_money , trip_cost(city, days, spending_money)


# trying to collect user data


#remaining code removed for minimal reproducible question :)


while True: 
    take_input()
```

Comment: Do you have a *question*? If you just want that block of code explained to you, see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/3001761; that's far too broad, be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while True` is a basic of Python.
It means "Do This Forever".
It is important for projects that run forever and never stop.
You can break it by `break`.

I will talk about your code. You are using `return` but you are not doing anything with your returned variables. Example you can print them using `print()`

Example:

```py
def take_input():
    print (" ")
    city = input("which city do you wish to travel to? \n Options are: delhi, kolkata, bombay, bengaluru : ")
    city.lower()
    print (" ")
    days = int(input("How many days are you travelling for? eg 1 - 100 : ")) 
    nights = days - 1
    print (" ")
    spending_money = int(input("How much spending money do you plan on carrying?, eg 100 - 10000 : "))
    return city, days, spending_money , trip_cost(city, days, spending_money)


# trying to collect user data


#remaining code removed for minimal reproducible question :)


while True:
    myvar = ", "
    mylist = []
    for i in take_input():
        mylist.append(str(i))
    print("Returned values:",myvar.join(mylist))
```

Comment: Everything here is true, but it's a lot of guesswork to get here from the question asked, and hard to tell as a reader if it even *is* a definitive answer (and thus, hard to know how to vote). Generally, we advise getting the OP to clarify a narrow, specific question before answering it -- see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and [How to deal with questions of the type "I don't understand how ${this code} works"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797)

Comment: ...and btw, code formatting should only be used for *code*, not emphasis. `Do This Forever` is not code; consider bolding or italics instead. See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990) on [meta].

Comment: I did not understand what is my mistake? I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it. Thanks for warning.